# is there an icsharp function for auto completed fill symbol like ) when you enter (

Tags: c#, icsharpcode

I am trying to do a function that using the icsharp text editor to auto-fill symbol like ) when you enter (;

Comment: Doesn't VS 2017 do this for you anyway?

Comment: i means that i am working on doing a ide to complete this function 。 if i can't explain claer ，i am so sorry for that because my english very worse

Comment: Just use VisualStudio 2017/2019, if you want this kind of support.